# How to record the video streaming using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Currently i am doing some R & D on JMeter. So i just want to know that can we do the video streaming recording using the JMeter? If yes, can any one tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

could you please clarify what do you mean under video streaming recoring using the Jmeter? If I understood you properly you expect from jMeter some functional testing possibilities.
 But  the matter is that jMeter tool is mostly purposed for load testing.
Look  some useful manuals on jMeter to make things clear:

- [Apache jMeter. What can I do with this?](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Getting started with jMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/get-started-scripting-jmeter)
- [Load testing with jMeter](http://java.dzone.com/articles/http-load-testing-jmeter)

Comment: HI eugene,

First of all thanks for the response. But i too know the difference between functional and non-functional testing.
I understood that you did not understand my requirement.
My requirement is like 100 users whats to view the same video online at a time? So can you please tell me the steps know. Sorry if you are not able to understand my requirement still.. :(

Comment: ok. got your question. Soon I'll post the idea I got on your problem